# Javascript or CSS fix for 100% <div> that doesn't fill page when IE11 is zoomed

Tags: javascript, css, zooming, internet-explorer-11

I have a **scrolling <div>** that is supposed to **fill the visible area of the page:**

```
<div id=allcontent style="width:100%;height:100%;overflow:scroll">
   (all page content)
</div>
```

**When I zoom in with ctrl+ IE11**, there is **extra space below and to the right** of my div, where I see the <body> background color.

I would like to **resize the "allcontent" div** to fill the page when IE zooms in, but I can't find a way to get the **actual page size** using javascript.

Is there either:

1. a way to get the real page size from IE11 a**fter clicking ctrl+**, or
2. a way to **specify the <div> dimensions in CSS** that will cause it to resize correctly with the page?

I have tried all sorts of measurements like ocument.body.clientWidth but not found anything that applies to the newly visible area outside of my <div>.

*Even weirder*: **the page slowly scrolls** to cover up the (wrongly) exposed body color.

Comment: The reason for doing this is to have a fixed element floating over a scrollable element on Mac/Safari. The whole page has to be in a scrollable <div> or else fixed and non-fixed elements scroll differently when pinch-to-zoom is used.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "**auto zoom to viewport width**" feature of **IE11**. The fix was to add the following to my CSS:

```
@media screen {
  @-ms-viewport {
    width: device-width;
  }
}
```

*Microsoft:* Internet Explorer... automatically scales content when the window is narrower than 1024 pixels... in cases where this automatic scaling is not needed or desired, the device-width keyword... signifies that the page is optimized to work well regardless of the width of the device.

I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573060/disable-internet-explorer-11-auto-scaling-zoom-to-viewport-width-ie11).